# JButton actionListener

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I programmed a JFrame that have a Button and JList , and when i click on the Button , the JList list will be displayed . Instead it shows nothing  unless i click on maximaze , or refresh the frame.
the button listener class

```
class b0listener implements ActionListener{

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    MessageList.removeAll();    
                    Messages = new JList(lireRepertoire("C:/Documents and Settings/Java/eclipse data file"));


                    Pane =new JScrollPane(Messages);
                    Pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
                    //Messages.setMaximumSize(MessageList.getPreferredSize()) ;
                    MessageList.add( Pane);

                }}
```

the class constructor code

```
Fframe.setTitle("Boite Message");
        Fframe.setSize(800,300);
        Fframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Fframe.setVisible(true);    
        //  panels Layout 

        ButtonMenu.setLayout(new BoxLayout(ButtonMenu, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));//Jpanel
        MessageList.setLayout(new FlowLayout());//JPanel
        ButtonMenu.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        MessageList.setBackground(Color.orange);
        MessageList.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));

                Fframe.add(ButtonMenu,BorderLayout.WEST);
        Fframe.add(MessageList,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        ButtonMenu.add(b0);
                b0.addActionListener(new b0listener());
                 Pane =new JScrollPane(Messages);
        Messages.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,250));
        //Pane.setMaximumSize(MessageList.getSize()) ;
        MessageList.add( Pane);
```

I already declared the Jpanels and Jframe , button as class members

Comment: Maybe there is a semicolon missing. How should we know if you don't show us how you do it. Please post a SSCCE.

Comment: Maybe try `pane.repaint()` at the end of `actionPerformed`.  By the way, never start a variable name with a capital in Java: Pane -> pane.  Capital are for class names.  It's not enforced; it's just a convention.

Comment: It is not common practice to have an extra class for each action listener. Let's say you have 15 buttons. Would you create 15 additional classes implementing ActionListener? Check the Java Tutorial for applications that do something similar to what you need and try to conform to the standards. Also class names should better start with a capital letter.

Comment: @Costis - certainly, if the 15 buttons are doing separate thingies: that's what OO is about. But use Action instead of ActionListener

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, learn an use the proper Java naming conventions. Variables should not start with an upper case character.

When dynamically adding/removing components from a panel you need to revalidate() the panel:

```
messageList.add( pane); 
messageList.revalidate();
messageList.repaint();
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of changing the components inside your frame you should instead think about your design and if it really is necessary to do so.

In your case the only effect is to change the content inside a `JList`. Therefore you should not rebuild the GUI but instead use the view-model separation and change the model content only. You can find an example in [How to Use Lists - Adding Items to and Removing Items from a List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#mutable).

Comment: 1+ for the best answer which is often not the direct answer to the original question but rather the solution to the original problem

Answer (score 1):

Call

```
// Add the component againt to appear in the interface.
Fframe.add(MessageList,BorderLayout.CENTER);
Frame.repaint();
```

This is because, if you add components to the frame, calling repaint will refresh the underlying structure with the interface.

Comment: I added  it at the end of the listener class and it  only remove the Jlist from the MessageList panel

Comment: Can u plz change the naming as per conventions. It is causing chaos while understating which one is class, while which is the variable!

Comment: Add the messageList component once again after calling the actionlistener (I have edited the answer as well). It will do.